# Appbar layout hiding ViewPager's background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying make `collapsingtoolbar` layout. Everything is working fine except the fact that the background that I set for `viewpager` is hidden by `appbarlayout`. I changed the background of `appbarlayout` to transparent but it resulted in a semi transparent view. I tried out changing the backgrounds of various layout but not luck. Help me out please.

Below is the screenshot:

[image]

Xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">



<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinate_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >





    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="AAAAAAAA"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp" />



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/viewpagertab"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_keyboard_arrow_right" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>







<com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.SmartTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewpagertab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    app:stl_indicatorAlwaysInCenter="false"
    app:stl_indicatorWithoutPadding="false"
    app:stl_indicatorInFront="false"
    app:stl_indicatorInterpolation="smart"
    app:stl_indicatorGravity="center"
    app:stl_indicatorColor="#6a000000"
    app:stl_indicatorThickness="30dp"
    app:stl_indicatorWidth="110dp"
    app:stl_indicatorCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:stl_overlineColor="#4D000000"
    app:stl_overlineThickness="0dp"
    app:stl_underlineColor="#ffffff"
    app:stl_underlineThickness="0dp"
    app:stl_dividerColor="#ffffff"
    app:stl_dividerThickness="0dp"
    app:stl_defaultTabBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextAllCaps="false"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextColor="#ffffff"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextSize="16sp"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextHorizontalPadding="30dp"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextMinWidth="0dp"
    app:stl_distributeEvenly="false"
    app:stl_clickable="true"
    app:stl_titleOffset="24dp"
    app:stl_drawDecorationAfterTab="false"
    app:stl_customTabTextLayoutId="@layout/custom_tab_with_typeface"
    app:stl_customTabTextViewId="@+id/custom_text"

    />



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



        <li.yohan.parallax.ParallaxViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/party"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />







</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this
`app:stl_defaultTabBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`
 line from 
`com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.SmartTabLayout` thats the reason why its showing less transparent .. give the main `RelativeLayout` a `background:@drawable\party` 
and remove background from `viewPager` library.. or remove `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Comment: both giving the same result? with `app:stl_defaultTabBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground` and without it..

Comment: I have already given a transparent background to appbarlayout

Comment: `com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.SmartTabLayout` is sitting over appbar..

Comment: It is inside appbar

Comment: I run it .. in my phone its transparent... what is it ?? Is it an activity?? Where did u put the main background??

Comment: It is an activity...and the background is in viewpager
<li.yohan.parallax.ParallaxViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/party"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />

Comment: 1).> You have given the background of viewPager `drawable/party` as you have given the 2)`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` it will always come below the appbar and the background will come below the appbar.. you can remove the line and check

Comment: Yeah it worked but it messed up my collapsingtoolbarlayout

Comment: as i said give the relativelayout the party background and remove the background from the viewpager... it will work.. wont mess up..

Comment: I can't remove background from viewpager as it is a parallax viewpager and it needs the background. If I put the party background in relative layout the parallax effect won't work.

Comment: ok then give a bit transparent background to your `appbar` like `#B3ffffff` or `#66ffffff` else it would mess up.. and remove that line scrolling behavior..

Comment: or you can give both the relativelayout and the viewpager the background and keep the line.. `scrolling behavior`

Comment: I think my problem is solved partially, thanks to you. BTW in the above image you see, the appbar does occupy the width fully. On the edges you can see there is some space left, any idea why ?

Comment: keep the`coordinator Layout` as the parent layout instead of `relativelayout` and check the problem might go...organise it accordingly keeping coordinator layout as parent...and appbar as first child... if it works then please..update ur question as answered..

Comment: I did app:elevation="0dp" and it did the work. I'll accept you answer, thankyou.

Comment: elevation of `appBar`?? ..thanks for letting me know.. :)

Comment: Yes, no problem, happy to help :)